# Fastest way to insert thousands of rows into mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, optimization

Can anyone suggest the fastest way to insert thousands/hundreds of thousands of rows into a mysql table? Right now I am using executeBatch, but I was wondering if there was a faster way to do it?

```
try {
        Connection con = dataSource.getConnection();
        Statement statement = con.createStatement();


        for(int i = 0; i < value; i++) {
            DateTime f = DateTime.now().minusDays(i % 28);
            String q1 = "INSERT INTO table1_test (txid, time, badgeid, event_type, sensorid, shift, unitid) VALUES ('"+i+"', '"+f.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")+"', 'NA', 'EN', '100', 'A', '1')";
            String q2 = "INSERT INTO table2_test (txid, time, badgeid, sensorid, shift, unitid) VALUES ('"+i+"', '"+f.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")+"', 'NA', '100', 'A', '1')";
            String q3 = "INSERT INTO table3_test (txid, badgeid, time, shift, compliant, sensorid, unitid) VALUES ('"+i+"', 'NA', '"+f.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")+"', 'A', 1, '100', '1')";
            statement.addBatch(q1);
            statement.addBatch(q2);
            statement.addBatch(q3);
        }
        statement.executeBatch();
        statement.close();
        con.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

Comment: Consider combining multiple rows to the same table in one insert statement too. Otherwise, Prepared Statements are the way to go for you.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use 'LOAD DATA INFILE' query type to import data into database. I think, it should be possible also with jdbc.

Comment: LOAD DATA INFILE is not replication safe. may be the best bet is to batch up the inserts.